# Running a function while waiting for ajax request to complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to solve a problem I have and I am a bit stuck with how to do this.

I am currently posting to my PHP page via AJAX, and while I am waiting for the request to respond I am wanting to run a function that simply displays loading.. and adds an additional '.' every 100ms. My problem is How can I call a function and then 'stop' that function when my ajax request has completed?

I have tried some promise based code but I want to know what is the best approach to do what I am trying to do?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "controllers/register.php",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  beforeSend:() => {
    // Start LoadingBar() Here.
  },
  success:() => {
    // Stop LoadingBar() Here.
  }
})

function LoadingBar() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('para');
  elem.innerHTML += "Loading ."

  setInterval(() => {
    elem.innerHTML += " ."
  }, 100);
}
```

Any help or any direction on where I can find the information to figure this out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I call a function and then 'stop' that function when my ajax request has completed?

Use `setInterval` to add the dots to your progress bar, then clear the returned handle with `clearTimeout` when the request completes.

Here's a simple example just using a callback (assumes jQuery). The cool kids use either promises or async/await nowadays, but it all the same under the hood.

```
function load() {
  // Start the animation.
  $('#results').hide();
  $('#progress-bar').show();

  const timeoutHandle = setInterval(incrementProgress, 100);

  fakeRequest(function successCallback() {
    // When the request is done...

    // 1. Clean up the animation timer.
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

    // 2. Display results and hide the animation.
    $('#progress-bar').hide();
    $('#results').show();
  });
}

function incrementProgress() {
  $('#progress-bar').get(0).innerHTML += '.';
}

function fakeRequest(callback) {
  // This doesn't actually load data.
  // Launch your ajax request instead.
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cmacrander/7jsLyhkm/1/)

Comment: Perfect! By any chance do you have a example of this using promises or async/await? im just curious and would love to learn what the 'cool kids' use. Again Thank You!

Comment: MDN is a great resource. Check out the first code box for "Using Fetch," which demos using promises. You would do this instead of `$ajax`, assuming you're in a modern browser and/or you using polyfills. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach:
it will dispaly a gif spinner or loader on every ajax call on that page, so just add this function on your js file and give the path to that image.

```
  // Add Loader on every ajax calls
        $("body").once('body').prepend("<div id='spinner-amt'><img src='/assets/images/spinner.gif'></div>");
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(){
          $('#spinner-amt').show();
        });
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
          $('#spinner-amt').hide();
        });
```

and if you want to design the loader, just add the following css to youe css file. following css will show the spinner the middle of the page.

```
#spinner-amt {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 45vh;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is completely different from what is being asked.

Comment: I dont want a GIF to display. I want a Function to be fired. And stopped as I stated in my question.

Comment: so simply fire your function on the $(document).ajaxSend(function(){  });
and stop your function on $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){});

.

Comment: How would I start and stop my Function?

Comment: like this: 

 $(document).ajaxSend(function(){
          // Your Function
        });
and it will stop bydefault on ajaxcomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Now simply use `clearInterval` in the success callback to stop the function once the request is complete. Also, avoid mixing vanilla JS with JQuery.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eternalhour/hwjugtnL/2/) based on your code so you can see it in action.

```
function LoadingBar() {
  $('#para').html('Loading .');

  loading = setInterval(() => {
    $('#para').append(" .");
  }, 100);
}

$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controllers/register.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    beforeSend: () => {
      LoadingBar();
    },
    success: (data) => {
      clearInterval(loading);
      $('#para').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let elem = document.getElementById('para');
  elem.innerHTML += "Loading ."

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "controllers/register.php",
      data: $("form").serialize(),

      success:() => {
 let elem = document.getElementById('para');  
 elem.innerHTML += " ."

      },
error:() => {
          let elem = document.getElementById('para');  
         elem.innerHTML += " ."
          }
    })
```

before calling ajax call all loading to inner HTML and on success or error remove it

Comment: async :-  By default, all requests are sent asynchronously. Set it false to make it synchronous.  YOU can use this flag as per your need

Answer (score 0):

Use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Example:

```js
let intervalId;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "controllers/register.php",
  data: $("form").serialize(),
  beforeSend:() => {
    startLoading();
  },
  success:() => {
    stopLoading();
  }
})

function startLoading() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('para');
  elem.innerHTML += "Loading ."

  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    elem.innerHTML += " ."
  }, 100);
}

function stopLoading() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```